# EmberJs deprecate component lifecycle hook didReceiveAttrs

Tags: javascript, object, ember.js, ember-cli, deprecated

For the Ember version `2.16`, they have removed the arguments passed to the `didReceiveAttrs` component lifecycle hooks. Previously I was getting arguments in the form of an object.

`newAttrs:`

```js
EmptyObject: 
{
  dataTestId: "test-object"
  items: MutableCell {__MUTABLE_CELL__       [id=__ember1555539649631463096066386]: true, __REF__ [id=__ember1555539649631670217952659]: RootPropertyReference, value: Array(27)}
  prompt: SafeString {string: "Select an Initiator Group"}
  required: true
  selected: MutableCell {__MUTABLE_CELL__ [id=__ember1555539649631463096066386]: true, __REF__ [id=__ember1555539649631670217952659]: RootPropertyReference, value: undefined}
  __proto__: Object
}
```

After deprecation how to get such an object in the `didReceiveAttrs`?

Comment: you mean the arguments which are passed to `didReceiveAttrs(arg1, arg2, ..)` ? Could you explain it more clearly ?

Comment: So previously the oldattrs and newattrs were coming as objects from arguments in didreceiveattr component hook method. But since these arguments are now deprecated how do I get the same object? My logic is dependent on these arguments.

Comment: what was the previous ember version you were using ?

Comment: In newer versions of Ember (see @tracked decorator), you are encouraged to watch component API changes on individual API items.  This avoid unnecessary computation and clear path to identifying bugs and errors.

Comment: @shreya Could you please upvote my answer if you find it helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uh, this was the Deprecation Added in `2.12`. You can get Arguments in Component Lifecycle Hooks until `2.13.0`.

An alternative approach for getting the arguments in the hook after `2.13.0` is below,

Before:

```
didReceiveAttrs({ oldAttrs, newAttrs }) {
  if (oldAttrs.temp !== newAttrs.temp) {
    this.thermometer.move({ from: oldAttrs.temp, to: newAttrs.temp });
  }
}
```

After:

```
didReceiveAttrs() {
  let oldTemp = this.get('_oldTemp');
  let newTemp = this.get('temp');

  if (oldTemp && oldTemp !== newTemp) {
    this.thermometer.move({ from: oldTemp, to: newTemp });
  }
  this.set('_oldTemp', newTemp);
}
```

You can get more info from the official [deprecation guide](https://deprecations.emberjs.com/v2.x/#toc_arguments-in-component-lifecycle-hooks)

Answer (score 0):

There is ember addon which can provide changed attributes,

https://github.com/workmanw/ember-diff-attrs

Shorthand usage:

```
import diffAttrs from 'ember-diff-attrs';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didReceiveAttrs: diffAttrs('email', 'isAdmin', function(changedAttrs, ...args) {
    this._super(...args);

    if(changedAttrs && changedAttrs.email) {
      let oldEmail = changedAttrs.email[0],
          newEmail = changedAttrs.email[1];
      // Do stuff
    }
  })
});
```

Extended Usage:

```
import diffAttrs from 'ember-diff-attrs';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didReceiveAttrs: diffAttrs({
    keys: ['user', 'isAdmin'],
    isEqual(key, a, b) {
      if (key === 'user') {
        return (a && b) ? a.id === b.id : a === b;
      }
      return a === b;
    },
    hook(changedAttrs, ...args) {
      this._super(...args);

      if(changedAttrs && changedAttrs.user) {
        let oldUser = changedAttrs.user[0],
            newUser = changedAttrs.user[1];
        // Do stuff
      }
    }
  })
});
```